# Accessing object of other class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to set `NSString`  to `NSTextField` of ClassB where the method is called in ClassA. But the `NSTextField` is not initializing the value of `NSString`.

**classB.h**

```
   NSString *folderPath;
```

**ClassB.m**

```
  - (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
    {
       self = [super initWithWindow:window];
       if (self) {

       [alertWindow setIsVisible:NO];

       [pdfStatusText setStringValue:@"Null"];
       }

      return self;
    }

    -(id)initWithAlertWindowControllers:(NSString*)fileName andTitle:(NSString *)title
    {
       //some part of code here
       //i am trying to set String value to the NSTextField pdfStatusText
       folderPath=fileName; 
       [pdfStatusText setStringValue:folderPath];     
    }  


    - (void)windowDidLoad
    {
       [super windowDidLoad];
       [self.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

    }
```

**classA.m**

```
     _alertWindow = [[AlertWindowController alloc] initWithAlertWindowControllers:Path andTitle:@"Project"];
```

Thank you..

Comment: Please show the whole of that `init` method; the devil is in the detail...   £1 says `pdfStatusText == nil`.

Comment: `NNString`? Don't you mean `NSString`?

Comment: Why is this tagged for iOS?

Comment: Please use the debugger.  As I already mentioned I am not convinced `pdfStatusText` is initialised correctly. If it's an `IBOutlet` (which it must be), ensure it's connected correctly in IB.  At any rate confirm if it's initialised using the debugger.

Comment: Ya sure. But pdfStatusText it's an IBOutlet and it's connected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your codes should work, try to write NSlog into your method something like it and be sure if your method is working, and then probably your problem is because of your textField `-(id)initWithAlertWindowControllers:(NSString*)fileName andTitle:(NSString *)title
        {
            NSLog(@"Is it working?");

            //some part of code here
            //i am trying to set String value to the NSTextField pdfStatusText
            folderPath=fileName;

            pdfStatusText.Text=title;
        }`

and maybe you should try something like  `pdfStatusText.delegate=self`;  in your view did load method.

Comment: How does setting delegate to textview will make an impact here?...though its not getting initialized..as per OP...

Comment: Thanks for information . Yes i m not sure about it , just an opinion so its why i said maybe you should try. His code should work , his problem because of his method isn't working or his textfield doesn't work normally.

Answer (score 0):

Is you set the value of NSTextField of class B in class A, class A will create a new instance of NSTextField and your textfield will not be initialised.
All you have to do is create a IBOutlet of class B in class A. And in the xib drag two NSObject and set their class to class A and class B. Now bind newReferencingOutlet of class B to the IBOutlet object you created in class A by ctlr+drag from classB to classA in xib.

now call the method of class B in class A using this IBOutlet object rather than a new instance of class B.